# Ignore UTF-8 BOM with csvsimple?

Tags: unicode, csvsimple

I am currently using `csvsimple` to include some external data in a document processed with pdfLaTeX. The entire project uses UTF-8 as encoding. The original data is maintained in an Excel 2010 file, and since Excel does not support exporting to UTF-8 CSV directly, I have to go through a rather cumbersome process:

- export to CSV
- open with Notepad
- save from notepad, changing the encoding

This process adds a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) to the CSV file - `0xef 0xbb 0xbf`. On my Windows desktop, this does not seem to be a problem, but the CI build on a Linux box breaks down with `Missing \endcsname inserted.`. Is there a way to tell `csvsimple` to ignore the BOM or do I have to edit it out before the compilation starts?

Related: [Google docs to TeX and pdf shell script produces a blank first page, and gives me a “! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.” error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284916/90087)

Comment: Several editors don't add a BOM, which seems to be characteristic with Notepad. There are utilities that change the encoding without the need of opening an editor (and don't add the BOM) like [Charco](http://www.marblesoftware.com/Marble_Software/Charco.html) but there are surely several others. I'm quite surprised that a well known application doesn't allow exporting as UTF-8 in 2014 (29 years after its first release).

Comment: @egreg You're right, but I was equally surprised that a well known (text) file processing software is unable to handle BOMs in the input :-)

Comment: TeX predates UTF-8 by several years. Maybe this could be a feature request for the next release of TeX Live.

Comment: Is using another editor than Notepad an option? Notepad++ e.g. allows to save without BOM.

Comment: The BOM problem may be `pdflatex` specific. I run a test with `xelatex` using `csvsimple` and a BOM coded input file without problems.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Using another editor is definitely possible and will probably be my workaround for the time being. Excel apparently throws out UTF16 or Windows-1252, and I just need some tool to convert this to UTF-8. Switching to `xelatex` probably won't be an option - it's a rather large project, and from my experience, changing the compiler tends to break a lot of stuff...

Comment: Maybe I found a solution for you (see my answer). This worked with my test file using `pdflatex`. Nevertheless, using another editor may be better than hacking the characters (?).

Comment: Do you use Notepad or Notepad++?  With Notepad++ you can configure the encoding of the file. See menu encoding, switch to utfß.

Comment: (Extract from [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) The Unicode Standard permits the BOM in UTF-8, but does not require or recommend its use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you input the file you could try to simply declare the BOM:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FEFF}{}
\begin{document}
\input{test-with-bom}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would this answer have solved the following question?:   http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284916/90087 If yes, it would be nice to have it posted as an answer.

Comment: @AFeldman: No, in your case the \DeclareUnicodeCharacter would be too late.

Comment: Thank you, appreciated. I was thinking that it would be preferable to have an answer that did not depend on sed and an external shell script in dealing with the google doc BOM.